# XCTAssertThrows crashes on 32 bits architectures

Tags: ios, unit-testing, exception, 32bit-64bit

For some reason, sometimes, uncaught exceptions will make the tests crash on 32 bits devices, *even if they resulted from a call initiated in an XCTAssertThrows test*, which is precisely supposed to test if an exception gets thrown. The exception making the tests crash defeats the purpose.

Comment: Are you using OCMock? I'm wondering if there's some interaction (or bug) that's causing this, because we've had it on two different projects.

Answer (score 2):

This broke as you describe in Xcode 6.3 - if you go back to 6.2 it should work fine. I'll be checking upcoming Xcode releases for a fix (6.3.2 still fails).

Adding the .m to the test target can cause other problems with duplication so is a short term workaround, at best.

Comment: I'm still seeing this behavior with 6.4 :(

Comment: I hadn't checked in a little while - XCTAssertThrows is working on 32 bit devices again with Xcode 7.2. It may have worked in earlier versions of 7.x, I just didn't try.

Answer (score -1):

Still don't know the reason, but fixed it by simply adding the tested class to the test target.